# how do ı connect html files each other with jinja?

Tags: html, jinja2

I'm trying to create a website, and for that I need to separate my codes. Here is my files structure:

- templates(folder):

  - index.html
  - header.html

I tried this code in my `index.html` file:

```
{% include "header.html" %}
```

but it didn't connect each other and wrote it in my website {% include "header.html" %} as a string.

where is my mistake, what can ı do? if you help me ı would very happy